# Syntax Error in INSERT INTO statement on vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

I'm trying to insert new records into my MS Access database from my VB.NET application. I can search, delete but can't insert - I get an error:

> Syntax Error in INSERT INTO statement

I have other forms which use different tables and same query but with the relevant attributes so this should be working. These a syntax right in front of me but I can't find it.

Issue is somewhere here:

```
Dim Insertquery As String = "Insert into Threat_Report(ID, Threat_Name, Vulnerabilities, Descriptinon, Skill_Level, Resources/Tools, Acess_Vector, Compromise) values (@ID, @Threat_Name, @Vulnerabilities, @Description, @Skill_Level, @Resources/Tools, @Acess_Vector, @Compromise)"
Runquery(Insertquery)
MsgBox("The record has been added successfully to the 'Threat_Register' table inside the database.", 0, "Information")
```

Add button coding:

```
Private Sub Addbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Addbtn.Click
    Try
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
        con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\ahmed\OneDrive\Desktop\ProjectDatabase2003.mdb")
        con.Open()
        Dim str As String
        str = "SELECT * FROM Threat_Report WHERE ID=@ID"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtThreatid.Text)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        If dr.Read() Then
            MsgBox("This 'Threat ID' already exists, please eneter a different 'Threat ID'.", 0, "Warning")
            con.Close()
        Else
            'Warns users of empty Textboxes or Dropdowns
            If txtThreatid.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("The 'Threat ID' field is empty, please fill this in and try again.", 0, "Warning")
            ElseIf txtThreatname.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("The 'Threat Name' field is empty, please fill this in and try again.", 0, "Warning")
            ElseIf txtVulnerabilities.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("The 'Vulnerabilities' field is empty, please fill this in and try again.", 0, "Warning")
            ElseIf txtTDescription.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("The 'Description' field is empty, please fill this in and try again.", 0, "Warning")
            ElseIf txtSkill.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("The 'Threat Actor Skill Level' field is empty, please fill this in and try again.", 0, "Warning")
            ElseIf txtTools.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("The 'Resources/Tools' field is empty, please select the Risk Probability.", 0, "Warning")
            ElseIf txtAcessvector.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("The 'Acess_Vector' field is empty, please select the Risk Impact.", 0, "Warning")
            ElseIf txtCompromise.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("The 'Compromise' field is empty, please select the Risk Level.", 0, "Warning")
            Else
                Dim Insertquery As String = "Insert into Threat_Report(ID, Threat_Name, Vulnerabilities, Descriptinon, Skill_Level, Resources/Tools, Acess_Vector, Compromise) values (@ID, @Threat_Name, @Vulnerabilities, @Description, @Skill_Level, @Resources/Tools, @Acess_Vector, @Compromise)"
                Runquery(Insertquery)
                MsgBox("The record has been added successfully to the 'Threat_Register' table inside the database.", 0, "Information")
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        con.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

RunQuery Coding:

```
Public Function Runquery(ByVal query As String) As Integer

    con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\ahmed\OneDrive\Desktop\ProjectDatabase2003.mdb")
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, con)
    Dim count As Integer
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtThreatid.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Threat_Name", txtThreatname.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Vulnerabilities", txtVulnerabilities.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", txtTDescription.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Skill_Level", txtSkill.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Resources/Tools", txtTools.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Acess_Vector", txtAcessvector.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Compromise", txtCompromise.Text)

    con.Open()
    count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
    Return count
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe `Descriptinon` should be `Description`?

Comment: And `Resources/Tools` should be `[Resources/Tools]`?

Comment: There are characters like `/` in your column names. You need to enclose the names of these columns with square brackets `[]`. Example: `[Resources/Tools]`

Comment: I fixed the Description misspelling and still have a error and like you guys saying, there a issue with Resources/Tools. Does only Resources/Tools have to be within [ ]?

Comment: I renamed Resources/Tools to Tools and this fixed the issue. Thanks for the help guys

Comment: I would think a space is required after the table name - so in place of this, Threat_Report(ID, Threat_Name, you should have Threat_Report (ID, Threat_Name,

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal, no, that space is not required. Neither is the one after VALUES. Works either way.